# Accessing container outside of controller but not able to inject a service

Tags: php, symfony

Due to the way I use certain classes I'm not able to do service injection, but I need to have access to the service container in them.

```
namespace DocumentsUploadSystem;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

class DocumentsUpload implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

        public function getData()
    {
        var_dump($this->container);
    }

}
```

If I call this method from controller like so.

```
use DocumentsUploadSystem\DocumentsUpload
...

$x = new DocumentsUpload($request)->getData();
```

and I get no errors but the container comes back as null. Is this a wrong way to implementing ContainerAwareInterface? I'm using Symfony 3.1

Comment: explain how you using certain class doing with you not able to do Service injection. In principle, service injection is always possible.

Comment: because I instantiate those classes in controller as a variable and I use __construct  to pass variables to those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing an Interface doesn't do anything. An Interface is a contract between the builder of the class and the user of the class guaranteeing the existence of certain methods - that is all. In this case, the `ContainerAwareInterface` guarantees that the `setContainer()` method is available. You then must **USE** it in order to set your container.

```
// MyController extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
use DocumentsUploadSystem\DocumentsUpload
...

$x = new DocumentsUpload($request);
$x->setContainer($this->container);
$xData = $x->getData();
```

For the record, I don't recommend injecting the entire container - only the actual services you require to accomplish your task.

Libraries like [KnpMenuBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html]) appear to be using this but in reality, they are automating the creation of the menu and injects the container for you. see https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Provider/BuilderAliasProvider.php#L122-L124

best wishes!

Comment: But is there a way to access container in a class without injecting it?

Comment: no. you cannot access something you didn't put there in the first place.

Comment: Of curse you can access the container without injecting it.  But how to do so is a big secret.  Even google won't give you the answer even if you search for "accessing the container outside of controller".  I think it is classified or something.

Comment: craigh why don't you recommend injecting the entire container? i read it more often but i dont see any reasons why. Remember that classes are passed by reference. Another point is that if you need more than one service in your class you can suffice with injecting the whole container instead of using two or more parameters in your constructor

Comment: @FrankB - Search for "Dependency Injection vs Service Locater" for a detailed explanation of the pros and cons of each approach.

Answer (score 0):

But in this example [https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html] they use the same technique and access container fine, it works there, is the service called else where for that?

```
// src/AppBundle/Menu/Builder.php
namespace AppBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

class Builder implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works because KnpMenuBundle automates the creation of the menu and injects the container for you. see https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Provider/BuilderAliasProvider.php#L122-L124

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks craigh, that snippet actually helped me a lot.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It would be very nice of you to accept it. thanks.